# How to debug `Push Notifications` if I have free iOS Developer Provisioning Profile?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification, provisioning-profile

I have no paid Apple Developer Certificate but I need to debug iOS Push Notifications.

How to debug iOS Push Notifications with free iOS Developer Provisioning Profile?

Comment: did you have `aps.cer` or `aps_development.cer` file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need aps certificate to register device and get push notification. So you can't do it without a paid account.

Comment: Thank you. Could you give me a link on this topic to official documentation?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1

Comment: But what about local notifications? Do I also need a paid account?

Comment: No, you don't need for local notifications.